# Pin Tool Segmentation Fault for Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, intel-pin

I have successfully run the pin with one of its own example tool inscount for ubuntu 12.04.
But I face a different situation for ubuntu 17.04 version. Here what it showed:

```
A: Source/pin/injector_nonmac/auxvector.cpp: CopyAux: 291: unexpected AUX VEC type 26

NO STACK TRACE AVAILABLE
Detach Service Count: 1
Pin 3.2
Copyright (c) 2003-2016, Intel Corporation. All rights reserved.
@CHARM-VERSION: $Rev: 81201 $
C: Injector exited with signal 6
E: Wait for injector failed: No child processes
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Any guess what could be the reason?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Support for the Linux kernel for this version of Ubuntu probably wasn't added yet. Try to run Pin with the `-ifeellucky` command line knob, this may temporarily fix the issue until a new Pin version comes out.